# Is 'what' used as a modifier in this question?

Tags: grammar, american-english, questions

Is 'what' used as a modifier in the question "what happened?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_modifier), a modifier

can be dropped and the grammatical meaning of the sentence is unaltered. It is fairly difficult to call

> 'What happened?'

a sentence in the first place, if you were to drop the 'what', very few people can get away with just 'happened?'. I would answer your question 'no', because 'happened?' has two meaning at least, a question and as a statement. Adding 'what' makes it a question.

Comment: Thank you. But if we have the question "How far is it?" I think "How" works as a modifier. Right?

Comment: Different question. Things don't 'work' as modifiers, they can be dropped and the sentence is the basically the same. For example in 'the red ball' red is a modifier, we can drop it to get 'the ball', and nothing has really changed.

Comment: Thanks. I was confused because I asked someone and he said that in a question like: Who is your boss? the word "Who" acts as a modifier for "boss"

Comment: @ZoltanKing - In the sentence _Who is your boss?_ the word _who_ is a pronoun. (Grammatically, it's basically the same as _She is my boss_.) You may find [this lesson on modifiers](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/modifiers_modify.htm) helpful.